# Android Studio: How to write a ringtone / notification / alarm audio file to storage and see it in the settings

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, ringtone

So this functionality was working previously, but I guess somewhere when I upgraded versions, it does not anymore.

I want to create dynamically an audio file (this is working), and copy it to the storage (this is working, it is currently copied to my local app storage :

- Android/data/com.mypackagename/files/xxx.mp3

Then I create a new ContentValues with the data & metadata and insert it into `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`.

After that I set ringtone and launch ringtone picker to check:

```
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(_instance, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, newUri);                  
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_DEFAULT_URI, newUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

But the ringtone set is only the ID of the media, not the name, and I can't find it in the list..

I though the Media wasn't scanned, so i tried this beforehand:

```
Intent scanFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, newUri);
sendBroadcast(scanFileIntent);
```

I'm not really sure what this does, but it didn't helped.

Any clues what's going on with the current status of creating ringtone with Android Studio ?

Comment: `Android/data/com.mypackagename/files/xxx.mp3` Apart from that you did not post full path your file is in app specific directory and hence the MediaStore does not want to know about it.

Comment: Yes, but when I try to write to others directories it does not work. Seems like missing privilege to write to local storage. Then is it possible to write to the root "Ringtones" directory ? Or do i need to help the Media storage find reference to my app specific directory files ?

Comment: You can create a file in Ringtones directory using MediaStore insert() method.

Comment: And indeed you can also create a file directly in Ringtones directory.

Comment: Hmm ok so that's what is not working.. Is it considered a Local Storage, or External Storage ?

Comment: It is considered both. Blame google.

Comment: I do not need anything more that READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE right ?

Comment: And obtain runtime permisson for them.

Comment: All right, i have those, i'll run some tests to see why I can't write to this folder

Comment: Well, I think I tried everything, cannot write to */storage/emulated/0/Ringtones* folder. And all files that I can write in my "app package" folder can't be found from the ringtone setter. If you have any sample code that manage to do any of those 2, I'd be very interested.

Comment: Well i can create mp3 files in that Ringtones folder with new FileOutputStream. Android version of used device?

Comment: Thanks for your help, found my answer from the differences of Android version permission since 2020.. Not so easy to find in the official docs ^^. But now I can write in this folder so i'm happy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here was my error. I needed to correct some things in my Manifest to get the rights permissions:

```
//Without this folders will be inaccessible in Android-11 and above devices
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

//Without this entry storage-permission entry will not be visible under app-info permissions list Android-10 and below
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
android:maxSdkVersion="29"
tools:ignore="ScopedStorage"/>

//Without this entry the folders will remain in-accessible in Android-10, even if WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE as above is present.
<application
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"/>
```

The *Ringtones* external root folder is not accessible from basic WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions anymore. We have access to app specific external folder, & others ([link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage)).

Even the Media store does not give you access to this folder, so from Android 11 & forward, you need the *MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE* permission, that gives you this warning:

> Most apps are not allowed to use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Because you need to ask for this permission to the user, and he might refuse..

But if you want to do what I wanted to do, you'll need it..

Be sure that your app ask for the permission through:

```
// permission: Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
// permission_id: 1
public Boolean checkPermission(String permission, Integer permission_id) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(_instance, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(_instance, new String[]{permission}, permission_id);
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `so from Android 11 & forward, you need the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission,` No. Not needed. Every app can create mp3 files in public Ringtones directory on an Android 11 device. For Android 10 devices you need request legacy external storage indeed.

Comment: `Even the Media store does not give you access to this folder` Not true either. Every app can create mp3 files in public Ringtones folder.